# UML Class Diagramm - How to define attribute as simple structure

Tags: class, uml, structure, diagram

Within a UML Class diagramm, I would like to define a class attribute as a simple structure. For example, I would like to define the Structure "Data" with the fields "old" and "new" in my class as:

Data.old:double

Data.new:double

I do not want to associate a "Data" class, since a simple structure is sufficient. Is this possible in UML 2.0?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution would be to define a "Data" DataType with two attributes respectively named "old" and "new" typed as double. Then in your class you have to create an attribute typed with your create "Data" DataType.

Hoping it helps,

EBR